# Detecting zoom change in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, zoom

There is no appropriate zoom event listener in OpenLayers v5.3 yet, but there is a workaround suggested in [this ticket](https://github.com/quentin-ol/ngx-openlayers/issues/158):

> You can use `this.view.instance.on('change:zoom', evt => console.log(this.view.zoom));` where `view` is a `viewChild : @ViewChild(ViewComponent) view: ViewComponent;` to detect zoom changes.

Can anyone please explain to newbies how to utilize this? How to use that code with an instance of a map view which is usually got by calling `map.getView()`?

Comment: That syntax is being used with Angular.  You don't need a zoom change event, if the zoom changes so does the resolution, so you can use `view.on('change:resolution', function() {  });`

Comment: The 'change:resolution' event is triggered about a dozen times for one zoom level change. The intermediate values are non-integer and the last one is always integer as far as I can see. Is there a way to catch just the final integer value?

Comment: Mousewheel operations can sometimes leave the map at a fractional zoom level, but if you are only interested in catching integer values you could test `if (map.getView().getZoom()%1 == 0) {   }` inside the callback

Comment: Is it possible to the final value may be fractional?

Comment: In some situations it might https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.interaction.html but you can set 
`interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ constrainResolution: true }),`  as a map option to prevent it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To hook on zoom end event is fairly simple: listen to `moveend` event and compare old and new zoom:

```
var currZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
  var newZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
  if (currZoom != newZoom) {
    console.log('zoom end, new zoom: ' + newZoom);
    currZoom = newZoom;
  }
});
```

If you want to catch zoom start, it's more complicated. I found a way but I don't like it, it's not how it should be done. I noticed that exposed method `view.animate` is called before any animated map event. I replaced it with my own, where I check for zoom, and then call original method:

```
view.origAnimate = view.animate;

view.animate = function(animateSpecs) {
  if (typeof animateSpecs.resolution !== 'undefined') {
    var currZoom = this.getZoom();
    var newZoom = this.getZoomForResolution(animateSpecs.resolution);
    if (newZoom != currZoom)) {
      console.log('zoom start, new zoom: ' + newZoom);
    }
  }
  this.origAnimate(animateSpecs);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, TomazicM. This solution works equally well as the one suggested by Mike in the question comments. With `moveend` event you have to filter map pan events where as with `change:resulution` you have to filer intermediate zoom change events.

Answer (score 8):

there is a simpler way for you to do it:

```
map.getView().on('change:resolution', (event) => {
    console.log("zoom changed");
});
```

Comment: Hm this sounded like a good solution and I also expected this to work from the docs, but unfortunately this does not have an effect in my case :S

Comment: works fine with OL 7.3+